# Как сделать выполнение JS скрипта ДО начала загрузки HTML страницы

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Делаю браузерное расширение для Chrome (для личных целей, не на продакшен), функционал простой: опустошение содержимого ВСЕХ `<script>...</script>` на посещаемой странице.

А конкретно хочу, чтобы попадая на сайт в процессе загрузки страницы Не загружалось все то, что заключено в тег скрипт. Пока что получается опустошать все скрипты после загрузки страницы.

Подключаю скрпти в HEAD:

```
let all_scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

for (let i = 0; i < all_scripts.length; i++) {
    let elem_2 = all_scripts[i];
    elem_2.removeAttribute("src");
    elem_2.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Работает, все внутренности тегов script исчезают. Но как Вы понимаете, браузер это содержимое уже успел "запомнить"

По этому хочу, чтобы Это все выполнялось ДО загрузки страницы (если возможно)

ЗЫ - Вариант с отключением JS в настройках браузера меня не устраивает. Задача написать расширение для легкой манипуляции (вкл\выкл в одно касание)

Comment: То есть вы вирус пишите?

Comment: Да, я знатный вирусописец. Говорю же, расширение для себя, не для продакшена. Зачем сразу ругаться?

Comment: Странная задача. Ну во всяком случае вы странно то это делаете, вместо опустошения можно, наверно, выкинуть ошибку, написав какую-то несуразицу, и тогда дальнейшее не должно выполняться

Comment: Ну ведь я для этого и задаю вопрос на SO, верно @GreatTech? Что бы понять в чем ошибка логики. Не что бы получить упрек и минус в рейтинг, а что бы стать лучше. Если Вы конкретно можете поделить примером как бы Вы это реализовали, было бы лучше

Comment: [Можете отредактировать вопрос](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL4PN.jpg), сниму минус

Comment: Справедливое замечание, на самом деле. Я обычно ставлю минусы по качеству, но тут поставил минус из-за задачи. Хотя если подумать, тут вряд ли можно вред какой-то нанести такой задачей, а сам вопрос написан хорошо.

Comment: Спасибо, я апдейтнул вопрос. Если технически эта задача не реализуема - вопросов нет! Но хочу копнуть, В этом же расширении есть принудительное "убрать target='blank' " со всех ссылок на странице, так как это часто бесит при серфинге. В общем просто пытаюсь браузер заточить под себя)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте завязаться на события onCommitted или onDOMContentLoaded
[https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation)

Или посмотреть как написаны какие-нибудь блокировщики рекламы типа adBlock или Noscript